# Clarification on a proof for the sufficient (coordinatewise) condition on differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

The following is from the book called *Analysis in Euclidean Space* by Shurman et al., pp. 157.

The claim is that:

> Let $f: A \subseteq \mathrm{R}^n \to \mathrm{R}^m$ and $a$ be an interior point of $A$. Suppose that for each $i \in \{i,\dots,m\}, j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ the partial derivative $D_jf_i(a)$ exists not only at $a$, but at all points in some $\epsilon$-ball about $a$, and the partial derivative $D_jf_i(a)$ is continuous at $a$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

In the proof the author only considers $m = 1$ and $n = 3$ (this is not the question I'm having) by proceeding to show that the linear mapping $T_a(h_1, h_2, h_3) = D_1f(a)h_1 + D_2f(a)h_2 + D_3f(a)h_3)$ satisfies the condition that $f(a + h) - f(a) - T_a(h)$ is $o(h)$, i.e. that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{||f(a + h) - f(a) - T_a(h)||}{||h||} = 0$. To this end, the author writes

$f(a + h) - f(a) = f(a_1 + h_1, a_2 + h_2, a_3 + h_3) - f(a_1, a_2 + h_2, a_3 + h_3) + f(a_1, a_2 + h_2, a_3 + h_3) - f(a_1, a_2, a_3 + h_3) + f(a_1, a_2, a_3 + h_3) - f(a_1, a_2, a_3)$, and then claims:

> Because the partial derivatives exist, we may apply the mean value theorem in two directions and the one-variable derivative's characterizing property in the third

and states $f(a + h) - f(a) = D_1f(a_1 + c_1, a_2 + h_2, a_3 + h_3)h_1 + D_2f(a_1, a_2 + c_2, a_3 + h_3)h_2 + D_3f(a_1, a_2, a_3)h_3 + o(h)$, where the $o(h)$ is the Landau (vector)space of all functions $f$ for which $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{||f(a + h) - f(a) - T_a(h)||}{||h||} = 0$.

I get how the mean value theorem was applied in the two directions, but what I'm stuck at is how the characterizing property of the one variable derivative yields $D_3f(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ multiplied by $h_3$. Namely, we know that the third partial derivative at $a$ exists, but with what manipulation from the Landau space $o(h)$ can we claim that this leads to $f(a_1, a_2, a_3 + h_3) - f(a_1, a_2, a_3) = D_3f(a_1, a_2, a_3)h_3 + o(h)$?

Comment: This seems to me just by the definition of the partial derivative. Denote $g(x)=f(a_1,a_2,x)$, then $g(x+h_3)-g(x)=g'(x)h_3+o(h_3)$. And at $x=a_3$ it is exactly the needed equality. Also note that $o(h_3)\in o(h)$ because for any function $k(h) \in o(h_3)$ we have that $|k(h_3)|<\epsilon |h_3|\leq\epsilon \sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2+h_3^2}\forall \epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Koncopd I think you are correct! If you'd like to extend this comment into an answer, I can then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by the definition of the partial derivative.
$$0=\lim_{h_k\to0}\frac{||f(x_1,...,x_k+h_k,...,x_n)-f(x_1,...,x_n)-D_k f(x_1,...,x_n)h_k||}{|h_k|}$$
And this is the same as
$$f(x_1,...,x_k+h_k,...,x_n)=f(x_1,...,x_n)+D_k f(x_1,...,x_n)h_k+o(|h_k|)$$
And also $\forall k(h_k)\in o(|h_k|),\ k^*(h)=k(h_k)$ as a function of $h$ is in $o(||h||)$ because
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\ ||k^*(h)||=||k(h_k)||<\epsilon|h_k|\leq\epsilon||h||$$